# Can avro ignore or skip unknown fields?

Tags: avro

Can avro ignore or skip unknown fields when decoding records?  So far, I cannot find any information on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avro will ignore unknown field names when decoding Avro records. In the Avro Specification, under the [Schema Resolution](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution) section,

> - if the writer's record contains a field with a name not present in the reader's record, the writer's value for that field is ignored.